# Not able to add Image or Button in header in React Native Navigation 6

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Not able to add an Image or Button in the header in React Native Navigation 6. please refer to the below code and image.

```
  <NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={HomeScreen}
      options={{
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        headerRight: () => {
          <Button
            onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
            title="Info"
            color="#fff"
          />;
        },
      }}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

HomeScreen

[image: HomeScreen Header Image]

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.7",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
  "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
  "@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake": "^1.1.0",
  "i18next": "^22.4.9",
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-i18next": "^12.1.5",
  "react-native": "0.71.2",
  "react-native-config": "^1.5.0",
  "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
  "react-native-paper": "^5.2.0",
  "react-native-paper-dropdown": "^1.0.7",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
  "react-native-screens": "^3.19.0",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
  "react-native-webp-format": "^1.1.2"
},
```

Comment: What's surrounding the <Stack.Screen> component? There isn't quite enough information here.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I just Updated the code info, Please look into it.

Comment: What does <NavigationContainer> and <HomeScreen> contain? I ask because so far it looks normal.

Comment: I agree with you, But the image or Button is not visible in the header section.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```js
headerRight: () => {
  <Button
    onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
    title="Info"
    color="#fff"
  />;
},
```

You should be using this:

```js
headerRight: () => (
  <Button
    onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
    title="Info"
    color="#fff"
  />
),
```

Currently, your `headerRight()` function is not returning the `<Button>` as DOM. Notice the usage of `(` and `)` instead of `{` and `}`. No `;` needed at the end either since it's DOM.

Another way to write it is:

```js
headerRight: () => {
  return ( // <--- You need to return the component
    <Button
      onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
      title="Info"
      color="#fff"
    />;
  );
},
```

If you still have issues, I have a working Sandbox I can provide.

I hope that helps, cheers!

Comment: Please share the sandbox with me.